# Triangle with three corners, find area f(a) and when function has its min-value

Tags: mathematica-online

This is my code:

```
Clear[v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3, x, y, z, a, b];
u1 = 7.306;
u2 = 0;
u3 = 6.446;

v1 = 0;
v2 = 7.306;
v3 = 6.446;

w1 = 7.306;
w2 = 7.306;
w3 := a^2 + 6.446;

aa = {(u2 - u1), (v2 - u2), (v3 - u3)}
bb = {7.306, w2 - v2, w3 - v3}
cc = {w1 - u1, w2 - u2, w3 - v3}

Cross[bb, cc]

Norm[Cross[bb, cc]]/2

Minimize[(1/2)*(1976.889363026176 + 2*(-6.668 a^2)^2), a]
```

The question is that we have a triangle with two corners in (7.306,0,6.446),(0,7.306,6.446) and the third corner on the curve in space that consists of the points (7.306,7.306,a^2+6.446) where a is a real number. Calculate the area f(a) of the triangle as a function of a and find where the function takes its min-value. (positive oriented ON-base)

I have tried solving this problem for a while but I don't get the correct answer. Thankful for any help I could get.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

tri[a_] = 
  Triangle[
   Rationalize@{{7.306, 0, 6.446}, {0, 7.306, 6.446}, {7.306, 7.306, 
      a^2 + 6.446}}];

area = Area[tri[a]]

(* (3653 Sqrt[13344409 + 500000 a^4])/500000 *)

{min, arg} = Minimize[area, a]

(* {13344409/500000, {a -> 0}} *)

min // N

(* 26.6888 *)

Plot[area, {a, -2, 2},
 PlotRange -> {25, Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {HoldForm@a, HoldForm@area}),
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{0, min}], {0, N@min}]}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[tri[a][[1, 3]], {a, -2, 2},
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y, z}),
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
  Graphics3D[{tri[a]}]],
 {{a, 0}, -2, 2, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Verifying,

```
pts = Rationalize@{{7.306, 0, 6.446}, {0, 7.306, 6.446}, {7.306, 7.306, 
     a^2 + 6.446}};
```

The length of the sides

```
len = EuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[pts, {2}];
```

The semi-perimeter,

```
s = (Total[len]/2) // Simplify[#, a ∈ Reals] &;

area2 = Sqrt[s*Times @@ (s - len)] // FullSimplify[#, a ∈ Reals] &

(* (3653 Sqrt[13344409 + 500000 a^4])/500000 *)

area === area2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you but it's sadly the wrong answer :( I really don't know why no matter what I try I don't get the right answer. Can you see anything incorrect with the code I tried with? thank you again!

Comment: @Leolo.11 what is the right answer, as you seem to know it already? Bob's code looks correct to me given your statement of the problem so perhaps you have copied down some of the numbers wrong? Or perhaps the 'official' answer you have is wrong?

Comment: @flinty I don't have the answer but I am supposed to get correct on webwork which I don't. His code is probably perfectly fine as well as mine but that's why I want to know what might be the reason. I have checked my numbers several times.